# Spring WebClient toFuture() vs. block() - What's the main difference?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

My Spring Boot application uses `WebClient` to make calls to a remote API. I do have some difficulty understanding the difference between the following modes on how to use the `WebClient`.

**Option 1 - using block()**

```java
// WebClient
public Boolean updateUser(long id) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(USER_PATH).build(id))
            .body(Mono.just(payload), User.class)
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> Mono.just(clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()))
            .block();
}

// Caller
Boolean result = updateUser(5);
```

**Option 2 - using toFuture():**

```java
// WebClient
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> updateUser(long id) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(USER_PATH).build(id))
            .body(Mono.just(payload), User.class)
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> Mono.just(clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()))
            .toFuture();
}

// Caller
CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = updateUser(5);
Boolean result = future.get();
```

As far as I understand, using `.block()` blocks the thread when the `WebClient` makes its request and waits for a response.

When using `toFuture()` instead, then the `WebClient` runs on a different thread, thus it does not block. But is the thread not blocked anyways using the `.get()` method on the `CompletableFuture`?

When would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

In the second option, you allow the caller to decide when to wait, this looks more flexible than the first option.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
`Mono.toFuture()` is not blocking but `Mono.toFuture().get()` is blocking. `block()` is technically the same as `toFuture().get()` and both are blocking.

`Mono.toFuture()` just transforms `Mono` into a `CompletableFuture` by subscribing to it and resolving immediately. But it doesn't mean that you can access result of the corresponding `Mono` after this. `CompletableFuture` is still async and you can use methods like `thenApply()`, `thenCompose()`, `thenCombine()`, ... to continue async processing. `toFuture().get()` is a blocking operation.

```
CompletableFuture<Double> result = getUserDetail(userId)
    .toFuture()
    .thenCompose(user -> getCreditRating(user));
```

where `getUserDetail` is defined as

```
Mono<User> getUserDetail(String userId);
```

`Mono.toFuture` is useful when you need to combine different async APIs. For example, AWS Java v2 API is async but based on `CompletableFuture` but we can combine APIs using `Mono.toFuture` or `Mono.fromFuture`.